# Coverting List<Data> to JsonArray

Tags: android, json

I have a list of Data class. Is it possible to convert this list to JSONArray ? 
My data class:

```
public class Data {
    // private variables
    int _id;
    String _objectID;
    String _objectIDServer;
    String _type;
    String _date;
    String _json;

    // Empty constructor
    public Data() {

    }

    // constructor
    public Data(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    // constructor
    public Data(String objectID, String json) {
        this._objectID = objectID;
        this._json = json;
    }

    // constructor
    public Data(int id, String type, String date, String json) {
        this._id = id;
        this._type = type;
        this._date = date;
        this._json = json;
    }

    // constructor
    public Data(String objectID, String objectIDServer, String type,
            String date, String json) {
        this._objectID = objectID;
        this._objectIDServer = objectIDServer;
        this._type = type;
        this._date = date;
        this._json = json;
    }

    // constructor
    public Data(int id, String objectID, String objectIDServer, String type,
            String date, String json) {
        this._id = id;
        this._objectID = objectID;
        this._objectIDServer = objectIDServer;
        this._type = type;
        this._date = date;
        this._json = json;
    }

    // constructor
    public Data(String objectID, String type, String date, String json) {
        this._objectID = objectID;
        this._type = type;
        this._date = date;
        this._json = json;
    }

    // constructor
    // public Data(int id, String objectID, String type, String date, String
    // json) {
    // this._id = id;
    // this._objectID = objectID;
    // this._type = type;
    // this._date = date;
    // this._json = json;
    // }

    // getting ID
    public int getID() {
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting ID
    public String getIDServer() {
        return this._objectIDServer;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setIDServer(String objectIDServer) {
        this._objectIDServer = objectIDServer;
    }

    // getting type
    public String getObjectID() {
        return this._objectID;
    }

    // setting type
    public void setObjectID(String objectID) {
        this._objectID = objectID;
    }

    // getting type
    public String getType() {
        return this._type;
    }

    // setting type
    public void setType(String type) {
        this._type = type;
    }

    // getting data
    public String getDate() {
        return this._date;
    }

    // setting date
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this._date = date;
    }

    // getting ID
    public String getJson() {
        return this._json;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setJson(String json) {
        this._json = json;
    }

}
```

I get the list like this :

```
DatabaseDataHandler db = new DatabaseDataHandler(getApplicationContext());
List<Data> list = db.getAllData();
```

Last few hours I have tried lot of different ways, and none of them worked..
Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do that with the [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) library, in one simple line:

```
 // Convert the object to a JSON string
    String json = new Gson().toJson(yourList);
```

For more information, you can look this answer:

[Gson turn an array of data objects into json - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186806/gson-turn-an-array-of-data-objects-into-json-android)

Answer (score 3):

Create a `JSONObject`. This `JSONObject` will represent a single `Data` object. Then, continue to make a `JSONObject` for each `Data` object, and put each `JSONObject` into a `JSONArray`.

Example:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject();
    myJsonObject.put("key", "value");
    myJsonObject.put("key2", "value2");
    jsonArray.add(myJsonObject);
}
```

You will need to use your own data to put into the JSONObject. For example: `myJsonObject.put("id",list.get(i).getID());`

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for.. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library for this.

And check out this post:
[Creating JSON objects directly from model classes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930624/creating-json-objects-directly-from-model-classes-in-java)

Then once you have the objects, you can throw them all into a JSONArray