# How to add the details of the return of method in table using angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am uploading files using spring boot and angular Js, my java controllor return some details of file such as the date and the type and the inputs of the form wich are the name Of the uploader and the file , so when i click on import Report ,i can upload the file but i dont have the details added to the table , i have an empty row .So what am i doing wrong?

here's my form

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>name *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="NameOfUploader" class="form-control" required="required" ng-model="r.NameOfUploader">
                        </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label>file</label>
                            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" fileread="r.file">
                        </div>                        

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  ng-click="upload()">Import File</a>
                        </div>
                                    <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id_file</th>
                                <th>NameOfUploader</th>
                                <th>DateOfUpload</th>
                                <th>TypeOfFile</th>
                                <th>File</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="r in reports">
                                <td></td>
                                <td>{{r.NameOfUploader}}</td>
                                <td>{{r.DateOfUpload}}</td>
                                <td>{{r.TypeOfFile}}</td>
                                <td>{{r.file}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>   

                    </div> 


                    </form>
```

Here's my java controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload",headers=("content-type=multipart/*"),consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody Option<JSONType> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("NameOfUploader") String NameOfUploader,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                try {

                DetailsReport d2=new DetailsReport();
                d2.setNameOfUploader(NameOfUploader);
                d2.setTypeOfFile(file.getContentType());
                d2.setDateOfUpload(new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
                d2.setFile(convert(file));
                detailsReportRepository.save(d2);
                    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                    BufferedOutputStream stream =
                            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new  File("F:/FilesStore/" + d2.getId_file()+"-"+d2.getNameOfUploader())));
                    stream.write(bytes);
                    stream.close();
                   return JSON.parseRaw(d2.toString());
           } catch (Exception e) {
               System.err.print("erreur");
           }


}
            return null;

            }
```

Here's my Js controller

```
//Upload files
$scope.upload=function(){

        var fd = new FormData();
        var url='http://localhost:8080/upload';
        fd.append("file", $scope.r.file);
        fd.append("NameOfUploader",$scope.r.NameOfUploader);
       $http.post(url,fd,{
           transformRequest: angular.identity,
           headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
       })
       .success(function(data){

           $scope.reports.push(data);
           console.log(data);
           console.log($scope.reports);
       })
       .error(function(){
       });

}
```

Any ideas please? I really need your help

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(data)` in your success function?

Comment: Object {empty: true, defined: false}

Comment: Well that's why you have an empty row. What's the value of `JSON.parseRaw(d2.toString())` ?

Comment: for d2.tostring it gives me that :DetailsReport [id_file=151, NameOfUploader=jikia, DateOfUpload=2015-06-09, TypeOfFile=text/plain, file=importantbcp.txt] but when i do JSON.parseRaw(d2.toString) it gives me None !

Comment: Try dropping the `JSON.parseRaw` method call. You shouldn't be parsing JSON here anyways, what you want is to send a string representing a json object. try just returning `d2.toString()`

Comment: Then in your Angular Controller use `JSON.parse(data)` before assigning it to your scope.

Comment: You mean like this :  .success(function(data){
               var b=JSON.parse(data); 
                   $scope.reports.push(b);

Comment: Yes, presuming that `$scope.reports` is an array that exists already. keep in mind, though, that the `d2` has to be a valid JSON object before you call `toString()`

Comment: I make the changes you tell me and i change the retuen of the method in java controller to String since i change JSOn.parseRaw(d2.toString) to just d2.ToString but now it gives me an error :  SyntaxError: Unexpected token D
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: That means you're not sending valid JSON. I don't have too much experience creating JSON objects in Java, but here's a thread that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930624/creating-json-objects-directly-from-model-classes-in-java