# Build cusom json for ajax rest request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

Im trying to send a request to a rest API and granted my knowledge using jquery is not advance however through numerous tutorials I'm struggling a bit to build a request based on this swagger documentation.

```
{
"fields": {
    "": [
        {
            "NAME": "NAME"
        },
        {
            "ADDRESS": "ADDRESS"
        },
        {
            "EMAIL": "EMAIL"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

This is the model of how i need to send the Rest request, im able to do this using postman however i struggle to do this in javascript.

```
    var data = {};
    var json = [{ "NAME": "name", "ADDRESS": "address", "EMAIL": "email" }];
    data.fields ={json};
```

My problem is that in the model there is an empty quotation which im unable to replicate. I suspect that either the rest API is not the best or im missing something quite vital in building a request. See below for the actual ajax jquery request.

```
  var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlBase,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({json}),
        });
        request.done(function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
            $("#log").html(msg);

        });
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
    }
```

Error message based on the above request

```
Invalid field groups: [json] used in the search fields not found in duplicate store schema
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a json like this:

```js
var obj = {
  "": [{
      "NAME": "NAME"
    },
    {
      "ADDRESS": "ADDRESS"
    },
    {
      "EMAIL": "EMAIL"
    }
  ]
}
console.log(obj)
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: Thank you soo much, felt like i was just walking around a pond full of answers and you just pushed me in and told me to get on with it :). Would there be any sophisticated way of doing the above by any chance, perhaps a library that helps you build JSON based on a model?

Comment: I haven't tried this but as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930624/creating-json-objects-directly-from-model-classes-in-java) link you can do this in Java. Javascript I am not sure of.